# RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages (2)

Tags: linux-mint, rpm, deb

At https://superuser.com/questions/607493/rpm-should-not-be-used-directly-install-rpm-packages, this problem seems to have been solved. Problem is, that working with Linux Mint, this answer shouldn't have appeared in my console, for I should be able to use RPM and not necesarily alien command. However, I had to alien all rpm files to deb inorder to install LibreOffice. Why is this?

Comment: It is not clear at all what are you asking. Please include the important parts of the question here, do not just link them.

Answer (score 11):

Normally you install software or deb packages on Ubuntu/Mint linux via Synaptic, Ubuntu Software Center/ppa, or an apt-get command from the terminal. In another hand, Fedora, centos, mandriva, and redhat support rpm packages.

Someday you have to install rpm package to your ubuntu/mint linux/debian box, there is a utility called Alien, Alien will converts packages from one format to another with ease.

Here is how to install rpm packages on ubuntu, linux mint, or debian

Install alien and all the dependencies it needs

```
# apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
```

To convert a package from rpm to debian format

```
# alien packagen.rpm
```

Finally, install your package !

```
# dpkg -i package.deb
```

For more info, use

```
$ alien -h
```

Source: http://namhuy.net/1207/how-to-install-rpm-packages-on-ubuntu-mint-or-debian.html

Answer (score 4):

Linux Mint, being a Debian derivative, has a debdb instead of a rpmdb. Hence you must use dpkg/apt and not rpm/yum for the system to properly recognize the package.